# Equivalent definitions of cluster point

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ a first countable topological space and let $E\subseteq X$. For me a cluster point $x\in X$ of $E$ is a point such that for every its nbhd $U$ we find a point in $(U\cap E)\setminus\{x\}$.

> Now I am quite sure to have proved that $x\in X$ is a cluster point of $E$ if and only if there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}\subseteq E\setminus\{x\}$ that converges to $x$.

Indeed the implication toward left follows from the definition of limit while in the other implication we use the first countable hypothesis to create a complete system of nbhds such that $U_n\supseteq U_{n+1}$ for every $n$. Then for every $U_n$ there exists $x_n\in (E\cap U_n)\setminus\{x\}$ since $x$ is a cluster point of $E$. Then the thesis follows.

> Now if my reasoning above is correct, this question makes sense: can we delete the hypothesis of first countable? I think not but I didn't find a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the same argument for space that are not first countable. For example take $X=[0,\omega_1] $ and $E=[0,\omega_1) $. Then the ending point is a cluster point for $E $ but you can't reach it by a sequence from $E $

Comment: sorry what is $\omega_1$?

Comment: @Richard: It’s the [first uncountable ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ok thank you. I'm not familiar with this object. I hoped that there was a more immediate counterexample. Is there? Anyway do you agree with the sketch of my proof?

Comment: Try to look also this space https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arens%E2%80%93Fort_space

Comment: @Richard: Yes, your proof sketch is fine. A simpler example is to start with any uncountable set $Y$ with the discrete topology. Let $p$ be a point not in $Y$, let $X=Y\cup\{p\}$, and give $p$ co-countable open nbhds: $U\subseteq X$ is an open nbhd of $p$ if and only if $p\in U$ and $X\setminus U$ is countable. Then $p$ is a cluster point of $Y$, but no sequence in $Y$ converges to $p$, since no matter what sequence you try, $p$ has an open nbhd that misses the sequence completely.